# Thunderbird inbox wont open 12.04

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, email

I get the alerts for new mail and can compose new mail from the bar at the top, but the inbox refuses to load. Reinstalling did not work. The icon will appear on the sidebar but once clicked nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it goes to background process. You need to kill its process by

```
killall thunderbird
```

Then start that from anywhere you like.

```
thunderbird
```

I m not shore if this work. But my problem solved by doing this.